# How to remove my custom navigation bar from backoffice?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How to remove **my navigation bar** from *backoffice*,then how to add *OOTB* navigation bar once again?

Answer (score 0):

I think you remove your codes already but backoffice cache your changes. For resetting cache, use F4 key from keybord in backoffice. On right corner you see hybris icon, click on it and select reset.